# export into PDF everything in a panel content using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel and inside the panel there is a gridview and charts(fusion-chart).  What i am trying to do is to export everything in the panel as a image into PDF.  So far, i am only able to export the gridview and the chart is not showing up at all.  How can i export everything in the panel content as image into pdf format?  pls. help.  Here is my code:
I am using ITEXT Sharp

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();

}
```

Comment: moe have you stepped thru the code..? are you getting any errors

Comment: no, i am not getting any errors at all.  In my pdf, i see the code of the fusion charts instead of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing the control to a bitmap using [`<Control>.DrawToBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) and then drawing that bitmap into your PDF

Draw to bitmap will draw a control into a bitmap - think of it like hitting print screen.

So, in this case,

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mygraph.Bounds.Width, mygraph.Bounds.Height);
mygraph.DrawToBitmap(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(),new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0,0,mygraph.Bounds.Width,mygraph.Bounds.Height)
pdfwriterthingy.writebitmap(bm);
```

I'm making the huge jump that your pdf exporter has the ability to write bitmaps?

Comment: i am not sure if  i am following you here.  can u explain to me little bit more.  thanks

Comment: updated with a code sample, it might not be exactly right but assuming that your control is a regular control, then should be roughly right.

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Charts are Javascript rendered on the browser as far as I can find. In that case, "rendering" its HTML into a PDF isn't going to be particularly successful.

Fusion Charts offer [specific server-side handlers for JPG and PDF rendering](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2009/05/export-your-charts-as-images-or-pdfs/), you'll need to use those instead.

Here are some more resources from the Fusion Charts site:

- [Sample Applications](http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/sample-applications/) (scroll down to "Exporting charts as images / PDF demo"
- [Exporting Charts as PDF or Images - Troubleshooting](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/exporting-image/ECTroubleshooting.html)